# Syntax error: unexpected token 'export' after bumping @mui/material from 5.14.20 to 5.15.10

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, astrojs

Bumping the minor version of `@mui/material` from `5.14.20` to `5.15.10` I suddenly get a `Syntax error: unexpected token 'export'`.

This is confusing as I don't understand what could have caused this - a minor version bump shouldn't break something like this, also the release notes don't mention any breaking changes between the two versions.

This is the full stack trace of the error:

```
(node:79404) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/@mui/utils/generateUtilityClasses/index.js:1
export { default } from './generateUtilityClasses';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:356:17)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:305:7)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async BuildPipeline.retrieveManifest (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/buildPipeline.js:92:26)
    at async generatePages (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/generate.js:110:16)
    at async staticBuild (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/static-build.js:93:7)
    at async AstroBuilder.build (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:134:5)
    at async AstroBuilder.run (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:165:7)
    at async build (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/core/build/index.js:44:3)
    at async build (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/build/index.js:21:3)
    at async runCommand (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:116:7)
    at async cli (file:///HOME/project-main/website/node_modules/astro/dist/cli/index.js:144:5)

Node.js v20.11.0
```

The import doesn't happen in my code, so I'm not sure how I could fix it. I looked at the mui issue tracker but there was no mention of anyone else having this issue. For now I need to pin to `5.14.20`.